# how to convert part of html page into pdf using wkhtmltopdf or something else

Tags: c#

Iam using wkhtmltopdf for html to pdf conversion of an html page using C# code and it is working absolutely perfect but i want to convert a particular part of html page to pdf like by specifying div id of that part or any similar method.How can i do this?

Please help

Comment: Did you check the documentation? What did it say?

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new HTML page with just your `div` as a body:

```
<html>
  <head><title>...</title></head>
  <body>
      <!-- PLACE YOUR DIV HERE -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Since you already know how to produce a PDF from an HTML file, you know know how to produce a PDF from a DIV ;)

**BUT**: Of course the CSS is going to be all wonky, since the selectors won't match anymore etc. This is a problem for the general case, but I'm guessing in your specific case, you can make that work.